# Load bootstrap from cdn using asp-net-core with npm webpack

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npm, bootstrap-4

[image: Current project structure screenshot]

As you can see from the image above, I'm implementing a website with asp-net-core with bootstrap installed using npm.

I want bootstrap to load from CDN when it's on Staging/Production build, but I know the only way to do it is using  tag helper.

How can I achieve this when I'm using npm bootstrap?

Comment: No way, I think!

Answer (score 0):

You can use     
`<environment exclude="Development">` 
or `<environment names="Staging,Production">` 
or `<environment include="Staging,Production">`
to load js or css from `CDN`.

Introduced from [Environment Tag Helper in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/environment-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- other head tags -->

<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</environment>
</head>
<body>

<!-- other body content -->
@RenderBody()
<!-- other body content -->

<environment include="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
    </script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o">
    </script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>

@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Answer from [Using jQuery and Bootstrap from a CDN with fallback scripts in ASP.NET Core 3.0](https://andrewlock.net/using-jquery-and-bootstrap-from-a-cdn-with-fallback-scripts-in-asp-net-core-3/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is, those bootstrap, jquery.js importing is declared in "site.entry.js", which is created by webpack from npm. So I cannot separate depending on <environment> tag,

Comment: There is no need to separate `site.entry.js` which you just add to `<environment include="Development">` tag. The only thing you need to do is adding `<environment exclude="Development">...cdn url... </environment>`.

Comment: Add  CDN one to one match  `bootstrap` or  `jquery.js` in "site.entry.js"